# Linq query from 3 tables using Joiner table

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables, Customer, Surfboards, and CustomerSurfboards.  CustomerSurfboards is the Joiner table.

```
Customer      CustomerSurfBoards    Surfboards   
----------    -------------------   ------------  
CustomerID    CustomerSurfboardID   SurfBoardID
IsActive      CustomerID
              SurfboardID
```

I want to select all surfboards where the customer IsActive = true

And I need to do this in Linq using C#

Comment: FYI Google indexed this page in under 5 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from sb in db.Surfboards
            join csb in db.CustomerSurfBoards on sb.SurfBoardID equals csb.SurfBoardID
            join c in db.Customers on csb.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
            where c.IsActive
            select sb;
```

Comment: LOL, for some reason when I wrote that in VS intellisense was telling me it was wrong - thanks